# Extract last two elements of an array in HIVE

Tags: arrays, hive

I have an array in a hive table, and I want to extract the two last elements of each array, something like this:
["a", "b", "c"] -> ["b", "c"]

I tried a code like this:

```
SELECT
 *,
 array[size]     AS term_n,
 array[size - 1] AS term_n_1
FROM
(SELECT *, size(array) AS size FROM MyTable);
```

But it didn't work, someone has any idea please?

Comment: "it didn't work" is not informative. It could be an error of any kind or it could be wrong results. If it is an error then you should share the error message. If you got the wrong results then share it.

Answer (score 2):

1. `array` is a reserved word and should be qualified.
2. An inner sub-query should be aliased.
3. Array index start with 0. If the array size is 5 then the last index is 4.

---

**Demo**

```
with MyTable as (select array('A','B','C','D','E') as `array`)

SELECT  *
       ,`array`[size - 1] AS term_n
       ,`array`[size - 2] AS term_n_1

FROM   (SELECT *
               ,size(`array`)   AS size 

        FROM    MyTable
        ) t
;
```

---

```
+-----------------------+--------+--------+----------+
|        t.array        | t.size | term_n | term_n_1 |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| ["A","B","C","D","E"] |      5 | E      | D        |
+-----------------------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: I tried the code above on Hive 0.13 and I got error "SemanticException 4:15 Non-constant expressions for array indexes not supported. Error encountered near token '1'".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the error that you are getting, but it should be something like

```
select
yourarray[size(yourarray)],
yourarray[size(yourarray)-1]
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to extract the last element of an array in the same query (notice it is not very optimal, and you can apply the same principle to extract n last elements of the array), the logic is to calculate the size of the last element (amount of letters minus the separator character) and then make a substring from 0 to the total size minus the calculated amount of characters to extract

Table of example:

```
col1  |   col2
--------------
row1  |   aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd
```

You want to get (extracting the last element, in this case "-ddd"):

```
row1  |   aaa-bbb-ccc
```

the query you may need:

```
select col1, substr(col2,0,length(col2)-(length(reverse(split(reverse(col2),'-')[0]))+1)) as shorted_col2_1element from example_table
```

If you want to add more elements you have to keep adding the positions in the second part of the operation.

Example to extract the last 2 elements:

```
select col1, substr(col2,0,length(col2)-(length(reverse(split(reverse(col2),'-')[0]))+1) + length(reverse(split(reverse(col2),'-')[1]))+1)) as shorted_col2_2element from example_table
```

after executing this second command line you will have something like:
row1  |   aaa-bbb

***As said previously this is a not optimal solution at all, but may help you**